# List files that are larger than 100 kB

Tags: stat

I would like to list all the files in `~` whose size is greater than 100 kB but without using the `find` command. I need to do it with `stat`.

Comment: All files where? In one directory or everywhere on your system? What have you tried

Answer (score 1):

`stat` can't list files based on a condition, but you can combine `find` and `stat` to get them work together:

```
find -type f -size +100k -exec stat {} +
```

or to get specific outout for example files permissions:

```
find -type f -size +100k -exec stat -c %a {} +
```

---

Or write a script which only uses `stat`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $HOME/*; do
 if [ -f "$file" ] && [[ $(stat -c %s "$file") -ge 100000 ]]; then
        echo "$file"
 fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I use find, why don't just use find -type f -size +100k ?

Comment: I thought you might want to get your output by `stat` command, otherwise `find -type f -size +100k` would works fine.